# Memory leak in malloced pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-leaks

I am getting a two instances of memory leaks that I can't seem to solve. The first instance occurs from `char *temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));`, I use this variable at the beginning of a if statement and make sure to free it at the end, but I'm still getting a leak. The second occurs from `s = create();` and `s = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    char **data;
    int top;
    int size;
}Stack;
typedef enum { FALSE, TRUE } bool;
Stack* create(){
    Stack *s;
    s = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    s->top = -1;
    s->size = 10;
    s->data = (char**)malloc(s->size*sizeof(char*));
    return s;
}
void deleteStack(Stack* ps){
    if(ps == NULL){
        printf("No memory allocated in Stack.\n");
    }
    while(ps->top >= 0){
        free(ps->data[ps->top]);
        ps->top--;
    }
    free(ps->data);
}
bool full( Stack s){
    if(s.top == s.size-1)
        return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}
void push( Stack* ps, char* str){
    if(full(*ps)){
        int tempsize = ps->size;
        ps->size += 10;
        ps->data = realloc(ps->data, ps->size * sizeof(char*));
    //  char **temp = realloc(ps->data, ps->size*sizeof(char*));
    //  if(temp == NULL){
    //      perror("realloc");
    //      printf("Error! memory not allocated.\n");
    //      exit(-1);
    //  }
    //  ps->data = temp;
        printf("Stack capacity has grown from %d elements to %d elements\n", tempsize, ps->size);   
    }
    ps->data[++ps->top] = strdup(str);
}
bool empty( Stack s){
    if(s.top == -1)
        return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}
char* pop( Stack* ps){
    if(empty(*ps))
        return NULL;
    return ps->data[ps->top--];
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("Assignment 2 Problem 1 by Jasmine Ramirez\n\n");
    FILE *input = fopen("data_a2.txt", "r");
    if(input == NULL){
        perror("fopen");
        printf("File %s not found.\n", "data_a2.txt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    Stack *s;
    s = create();                <---16 bytes in 1 block definitely lost
    char str[255];
    char *temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));   <---1 bytes in 1 block definitely lost
    int i = 0;
    while(fscanf(input, "%s\n", str) == 1){
        if(strcmp(str, "pop") == 0){
            temp = pop(s);
            i--;
            printf("# of elements after popping: %d\tstring popped: %s\n", i, temp);
            free(temp);
        }
        else{
            push(s, str);
            i++;    
        }
    }
    deleteStack(s);
    fclose(input);
    return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out the reason for the 1 byte lost in `temp` and `s` is supposed to be taken care of by `deleteStack()`.

Comment: In this code — `char *temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)); 
    int i = 0;
    while(fscanf(input, "%s\n", str) == 1){
        if(strcmp(str, "pop") == 0){
            temp = pop(s);
            i--;
            printf("# of elements after popping: %d\tstring popped: %s\n", i, temp);
            free(temp);
        }` you leak because you unconditionally overwrite `temp` with the value from `pop()` and then free what `pop()` returned.  That makes it impossible to free what was originally allocated.  And `deleteStack()` needs `free(ps);` at the end.

Comment: `deleteStack` should not go on to do `ps->top` in the case of `ps == NULL`

Comment: You are allowed to use empty lines when writing C code, turning it readable to humans.

Comment: Agree with @Lundin. Please make it human readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this statement

```
temp = pop(s);
```

Pointer to earlier malloced memory is lost so it is leaked.

In `deleteStack`, you have not freed `ps`, so that's a leak too, as memory allocated to `Stack *s;` in `create` never gets released.

Answer (score 3):

You should `free(ps)` at the end of `deleteStack`.

The `temp` pointer to the single `malloc`d `char` is overwritten with the result from `pop`, so it is leaked.  Why do you need to allocate that single `char`?  Just initialize it to `NULL`, or leave it uninitialized.

In production code, you should always test the value returned from `malloc` or `realloc`, and should never assign the result of `realloc` over your only pointer to the memory you are trying to reallocate.  If it reurns `NULL`, you just leaked it.

Also, in `deleteStack`, you test for `NULL`, but then continue to dereference the pointer anyway.